# can you change the local dexie DB values of null to just a string with no value

Tags: javascript, php, dexie

so i update my dexie db with my sql db, but the problem is that some of the values are empty

THE PROBLEM IS THAT WHEN I WANT TO PRINT THE VALUE IN PHP IT PRINTS ALL THE VALUES AND THE
ONES WHICH ARE ""null"".... how do i fix this??

i am using datatables and i have a few columns which are linked and i still need to see that lets say the fuel col has nothing "" but it musnt show null

```js
db.fuel.put({                        
  department: data[i].department
});
```

Comment: Please add more details. Do you want to fix the printing part to not display the nulls, or do you want to avoid having the null entries in the database to begin with?

Comment: @TomJohnson  i dont want null entries in the database to begin with...so instead of null it must just be blank.... i am using datatables...i want it to be empty where "null"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this checks if the value coming from mysql is null then directly changes it to an empty string

```
            url: 'fuel_fetch_null',
            headers: { 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' },
            success: function(data) {
                //fuel
                db = db_open();
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                var  datas = data.data;


                for (i in datas) {
                    if(datas[i].department == null){
                        datas[i].department = '';
                    }
                     db.fuel.put({
                        id: datas[i].id,
                        department: datas[i].department
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```